# Why does 100 >> 100 and 100 >>> 100 return 6 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift):

> The right shift operator (>>) shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. Since the new leftmost bit has the same value as the previous leftmost bit, the sign bit (the leftmost bit) does not change. Hence the name "sign-propagating".

From what I understand, since 100 is `0b1100100`, shifting it 100 times to the right should yield `0b0`. However, when I run `100 >> 100` in Javascript (using chrome), it returns 6. Why is this the case? I am guessing it has something to do with JS's internal representation of numbers but would like to know more clearly.

Edit: The answer is still 6, even when using the unsigned `>>>` operator. Sign/unsigned does not seem to matter.

Unsigned operation [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift):

> The unsigned right shift operator (>>>) (zero-fill right shift) shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero bits are shifted in from the left. The sign bit becomes 0, so the result is always non-negative. Unlike the other bitwise operators, zero-fill right shift returns an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: Trying to do this operation in Rust results in a compile error due to overflow. As such, I think the reason for this is due to int overflow when shifting by large numbers.

Comment: Try `100 >> 31` and `100 >> 32`.

Comment: I would have thought that shifting 100 bits to the right would result in all bits falling off and you'd be left with just the sign, but it appears not to be the case... seems to be `% 32`d or something

Comment: Can't really explain why, but the [ECMAscript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-signedRightShift) says that the number is shifted by x modulo 32 bits, that is, shifting by 32, 64, ... will result in the same number, x >> 100 will in other words result in the same result as x >> 4.

Comment: I think that is correct. I now see that it is indeed shifted by modulo 32. So sad I didn't think to look at the ECMA specifications.

Comment: Related: [Javascript's Shift right with zero-fill operator (>>>) yielding unexpected result](/q/63276182/4642212).

Comment: @joachim probably cause it is "undefined behaviour" in hardware (or rather matches exactly what processors do at the circuit level) https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value to the right is taken mod 32. (i.e. Only the last five bits are used.) If you calculate `100>>32`, you get `100`, which is the same thing you get when you compute `100>>0`. After that, `100>>33` is `50`, and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Pro-tip: if you include a quote from and a link to the ECMAScript specification it’ll increase the quality of your answer and make this post [easily findable](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+url%3A%22signedRightShift%22).